# The meaning of "point" in the context of a line of scrimmage

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to Wikipedia, a [line of scrimmage](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_of_scrimmage) is "(American football) either of two imaginary lines across the football field touching one of the two apices of the football which point toward either the defensive side or the offensive side before the center is allowed to touch the ball before each play.".

Could somebody help me understand what "point" refers to in this context? Thank you.

Comment: "Point" is a verb in the above sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Apices* is one of the plural forms of [**apex**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apices):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *plural* **apexes** or **apices**
>   **1 a** : the uppermost point : VERTEX
>          // the *apex* of a mountain
>   **1 b** : the narrowed or pointed end : TIP
>          // the *apex* of the tongue

The more common word used in the definition is **tip**.

A football is an oval with two tips, and *point* is being used as a verb, not a noun.

As such, it could be rephrased in the following way:

> … one of the two *tips* of the football which point toward either the defensive side or the offensive side.

For a visual representation, look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mROnC.jpg), which shows a football at the line of scrimmage. One end (tip or apex) of the football points to the defensive side, while the other end points to the offensive side:

[image: football on the line of scrimmage]

The phrasing itself might have been simplified. In addition to using *tips*, it could have instead said something like the following:

> … the tips of the football which point toward the defensive and offensive sides …

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations !